# What is the Eclipse way to modify the workbench by switching perspectives or changing a perspective?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse plugin development. The plugin I work on has a perspective which is not best for a new use case my team needs to support. I want the workbench to change when the user opens a file with a specific extension. It could be a matter of switching perspective or to modify to the current perspective by opening and closing views.

What is the Eclipse way to achieve this?

It seems to me more user friendly to do this automatically but the more I read about it the more I have the impression that Eclipse is not designed with this in mind. Should I just create a new perspective and have the user open it instead?

Comment: There is no standard way to change perspective when an editor is opened

Comment: I don't need to open an editor, but to open and close several views.

Comment: You said 'I want the workbench to change when the user opens a file with a specific extension' - opening a file opens an editor, Eclipse doesn't provide any standard mechanism to open views or perspective when an editor opens.

Comment: I am sorry, my wording must be imprecise. With "opening" I mean double-clicking. In my context, the user do not edit the file, but visualize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse way is to ask the user via a ***Yes/No* dialog with a *Remember my decision* checkbox**, like in Java the *Debug* command or in Git the *Synchronize Workspace* command do:

[image]

See also the following preferences in *Window > Preferences*:

- *General > Perspectives*
- *Run/Debug > Perspectives*